# Insert node to a sorted list without head pointer

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Can someone improve this answer? I believe the AddNode function can be trivially small. It is a problem about inserting a node into a sorted linked list, but there is one caveat. You don't have the head pointer. So, the data must be swapped into the class if the node data is less than the head.

```
class SList
{
public:
    SList(int value = 0,
          SList* n = nullptr) :
        foo(value), pNext(n)
    {
    }

    void Output() 
    { 
        cout << foo;  
        if (nullptr != pNext) 
        {
            cout << ", ";
            pNext->Output(); 
        }
    }  

    void AddNode(int value)
    {
        SList* head = this;

        // Insert to front
        if (value < head->foo)
        {
            int temp = foo;
            foo = value;
            SList* pNode = new SList(temp);
            SList* pNextTmp = this->pNext;
            this->pNext = pNode;
            pNode->pNext = pNextTmp;
            return;
        }

        // Insert to end
        if ((value > head->foo) && nullptr == head->pNext)
        {
            SList* pNode = new SList(value);
            this->pNext = pNode;
            return;
        }

        // Middle case
        while (head)
        {
            if (value > head->foo)
            {
                if (head->pNext)
                {
                    if (value < head->pNext->foo)
                    {
                        SList* pNode = new SList(value);
                        SList* pNodeTemp = head->pNext;
                        head->pNext = pNode;
                        pNode->pNext = pNodeTemp;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SList* pNode = new SList(value);
                    head->pNext = pNode;
                }
            }

            head = head->pNext;
        }
    }

protected:
    int         foo;
    SList*      pNext;
};

void sortedListTest()
{
    SList* list = new SList(5);

    cout << endl;
    list->AddNode(19);
    list->AddNode(3);
    list->AddNode(8);
    list->AddNode(12);
    list->AddNode(33);
    list->AddNode(9);
    list->AddNode(1);
    list->AddNode(23);
    list->Output();
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: well, if you can't have a head pointer, you'll need a pPrev pointer. if you can't change the data structure, when you do the //insert to front, return the new inserted element so the caller holds the pointer to the head, otherwise the list gets split in a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First test if value less than head and create new head.
If value is greater than head iterate until next element is grater than head and insert before.

```
class SList
{
public:
    SList(int value = 0,
                 SList* n = nullptr) :
        foo(value), pNext(n)
    {
    }

    void Output() 
    { 
        cout << foo;  
        if (nullptr != pNext) 
        {
            cout << ", ";
            pNext->Output(); 
        }
    }  

    void AddNode(int value)
    {
        SList* head = this;

        // Insert to front
        if (value < head->foo)
        {
            SList* pNode = new SList(foo);
            pNode->pNext = this->pNext;
            this->pNext = pNode;
            foo = value;
            return;
        }

        while ( head->pNext && head->pNext->foo < value )
            head = head->pNext;

        SList* pNode = new SList(value);
        pNode->pNext = head->pNext;
        head->pNext = pNode;
    }

protected:
    int         foo;
    SList*      pNext;
};

void sortedListTest()
{
    SList* list = new SList(5);

    cout << endl;
    list->AddNode(19);
    list->AddNode(3);
    list->AddNode(8);
    list->AddNode(12);
    list->AddNode(33);
    list->AddNode(9);
    list->AddNode(1);
    list->AddNode(23);
    list->Output();
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

Basically copy element(after which insertion has to be done) and update next pointer and data of that copy. Special case needs to be handled for head.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class SList
{
public:
    SList(int value = 0,
          SList* n = nullptr) :
        foo(value), pNext(n)
    {
    }

    void Output() 
    { 
        cout << foo;  
        if (nullptr != pNext) 
        {
            cout << ", ";
            pNext->Output(); 
        }
    }  

    void AddNode(int value)
    {
        SList* current = this;
        SList* prev = NULL;

        while( current && current->foo < value)
        {
            prev = current;
            current = current->pNext;
        }

        if(prev)
        {
            SList *newNode =  new SList(*prev);
            newNode->foo = value;
            prev->pNext = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            SList *newNode =  new SList(*current);
            current->foo = value;
            current->pNext = newNode;
        }



    }

protected:
    int         foo;
    SList*      pNext;
};

int main()
{
    SList* list = new SList(5);

    cout << endl;
    list->AddNode(19);
    list->AddNode(3);
    list->AddNode(8);
    list->AddNode(12);
    list->AddNode(33);
    list->AddNode(9);
    list->AddNode(1);
    list->AddNode(23);
    list->Output();
    cout << endl;
}
```